# How to count items which meet a 'where' condition with multiple criteria in the same column

Tags: sqlite, count, where-clause

I am new to SQL and I am using SQLite to run sales analysis for a chain of retail stores.

I am currently trying to count the number of transactions which contain different categories of item.  The relevant columns in my data are uniqID (which provides a transaction ID) and category.  Each uniqID has one row for each item in that transaction, ie a transaction of three items would have three rows.  Each of those rows would have its own category, ie:

uniqID Category
103    Trousers
103    Skirt
103    Skirt
104    Jumper
104    Skirt

Is it possible to do a count function which counts the number of unique transactions which contain two different categories?  For example, how many transactions contained trousers and skirts? (In the above example, the answer should be 1!)

I have tried the following:

select count (distinct uniqID) where category = trousers and category = skirts;

However, it keeps returning the answer as 0, which I know is not true.  Can anyone suggest a way of rewording the query?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hmm the example of my data has not really worked - I was trying to create a table with the ID in the left column and the category in the right column...

Comment: Yes it's possible, of course, but how you know it's not true? Tried a `select * from yourtable where category = trousers and category = skirts;`? (btw you're missing the `FROM` keyword in your SQL query)

Answer (score 0):

category cannot have two different values at the same time, use 'or' instead of 'and'.

```
select count (distinct uniqID) where category = trousers or category = skirts;
```

Answer (score 0):

If anything, it should be

```
select count (distinct uniqID) where category = 'trousers' OR category = 'skirts';
```

Since the category in one row can't have the value "trousers" AND "skirts" at the same time.